# Notice: Undefined index: APP_NAME returns null

Tags: php, phpdotenv

I'm having a problem setting up phpdotenv in my PHP project.

`Notice: Undefined index: APP_NAME in /media/undefined/work/Php/miniframework/bootstrap/app.php on line 17`

My folder structure

miniframework

- app
- bootstrap

  - app.php
- public

  - index.php
- vendor
- .env
- composer.json

The code is from bootstrap/app.php file.

```
<?php


session_start();


require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';


use Dotenv\Dotenv;


$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__, '/..//')->load();


var_dump($_SERVER['APP_NAME']);
```

Comment: From the package's [github page](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) for `createImmutable`: "_Optionally you can pass in a filename as the second parameter, if you would like to use something other than .env_" You pass `'/..//',` is that the file you want to load?

Comment: My `.env` file not in the bootstrap/app.php it's in the root folder which is miniframework. If I don't pass anything as the second parameter it throws an error bootstrap/.env is not found.

Comment: The path can be set in the _first_ parameter, as said, the second parameter is the filename. Maybe try `Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__ . '../')->load()`.